# Validar si un elemento ya fue procesado

Tags: python

La idea del codigo es extraer informacion de la pagina ahi mencionada y con forme el usuario pida informacion el programa le arroje un resultado, aqui viene el problema, el ejercicio me pide que determine si la informacion recogida ya fue consultada o no, en dado caso de que se haya consultado, muestre en pantalla 'Ya consultado'. Este es el codigo:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX- 
1vSuGk3cDtavF2DdfsTTBFN6lGF52vksWxPvLVhRgiQKJInRzl_Eue2c_zInHDjgmzLFeQlBjjZ_cm5p/pub'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,'html.parser')
counter_items = soup.find_all(class_='c0')
count=dict()
for line in counter_items:
    line=line.text
    if not line.startswith("A:"): continue
    words=line.split()
    diales=words[1]+' '+words[2]
    count[diales]=count.get(diales,words[3:])
tp=sorted(count.items())
lista=list()
while True:
    n=input('Ingrese la emisora a consultar ')
    if n=='':break
    m=input('Ingrese frecuencia en la que se buscara la emisora ')
    m=m.upper()
    se=n+' '+m
    for k,v in tp:
        v=' '.join(v)
        if se == k:
           print(k,v)
           lista.append(se)
        if se in lista:
           print('Ya consultado')
```

Yo se que ese if no me va a servir en nada pero no tengo ni idea de que hacer, muchas gracias de antemano a quien me ayude.

PD: Yo utilizo la emisora 92.1 y la frecuencia mhz como prueba, el resultado es el siguiente.

```
Ingrese la emisora a consultar 92.1
Ingrese frecuencia en la que se buscara la emisora mhz
92.1 MHZ - eco f.m. 92.1
Ya consultado
Ya consultado
Ya consultado
Ya consultado
Ya consultado
Ya consultado
Ya consultado
Ingrese la emisora a consultar
```